# Nginx PHP as user?

Tags: php, linux, bash, nginx, permissions

I try to create Nginx and PHP8.2 shared hosting in Ubuntu 22.04.

I have two sites:
/home/meow1/public_html/index.php
/home/meow2/public_html/index.php

meow1 cannot open directory /home/meow2/ and is fine.
But /home/meow1/public_html/index.php file exec as "www-data".

When i try:

```
exec("cat ../../meow2/a.txt",$array);
print_r($array);
```

A php file inside meow1 user can read meow2 files as www-data :(

Any idea?

www-data can read /home/* folder by this config:

```
setfacl -R -m user:www-data:rx,d:user:www-data:rx /home
```

Comment: My first guess would be that you are using the same PHP-FPM pool for both applications. If so, you will for sure have the same user accessing your filesystem for both sites. I would try to configure 2 different pools. https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php

It is not clear why would meow1 look for out-of-bound files in your filesystem, are you using user input to access these files? If so, you might want to reconsider.